# Select statement selection through URL parameters

Tags: html, url, parameters

I'm attempting to alter the contents of certain parts of a HTML form through usage of the URL.  For a text field, I'm aware that this will suffice,

`http://<domain>?fieldname=ping&anotherfield=pong`

On the form there are multiple select braces (drop down boxes); Is it possible to pick an int or string value through the url for this?

There seems to be little documentation on this (or even people trying to do the same)...

Comment: On the face of it, this sounds like it would be quite dangerous. Without knowing more about what you're using to secure and validate your forms, I would say that you need to consider other methods to accomplish this -- if you truly need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified how you want to do this, but I'll assume that you want to use JavaScript:

To get a value from QueryString:

```
getQueryStringArgument = function(key) {
    var hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var gy = hu.split("&");
    for (i = 0; i < gy.length; i++) {
        var ft = gy[i].split("=");
        if (ft[0] == key)
            return ft[1];
    }
}
```

To set the selected value of the select list:

```
document.getElementById("sel").value = getQueryStringArgument("id");
```

Comment: This came largely from a lock of knowledge of what was happening and required serverside. This javascript is pretty much what I was looking for. (Previously I'd thought it was just an implicit transformation)

Answer (score 0):

> For a text field, I'm aware that this will suffice

No, it won't (at least, not in a generic way).

For a text field, the default value is specified by the `value` attribute. There might be a server side script that populates it based on query string data, but there doesn't have to be.

> On the form there are multiple select braces (drop down boxes); Is it possible to pick an int or string value through the url for this?

Again, this requires an attribute to be set (`selected` on `<option>`), and that could (again) be set by a server side script based on the query string data.